# Test a Flask view that requires specific configuration, data, and headers

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

There is a function decorated with `before_request` which processes authentication headers and sets properties on the `request`.  I want to test the `/status` route, but I do not see how to mock the headers and the `before_request` function.  The view also checks against the database, which requires configuration as well.  How do I set all three of these pieces when testing?

```
@before_request
def process_auth_headers():
    # Process auth headers and set properties on "request" object

@app.route("/status")
def status():
    # Check "request" object properties for auth results
```

```
import unittest
import os
from ccbackendvsphere.api.v3 import app

class TestFlaskApp(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.confg['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')
        self.flask_app = app.test_client()

    def test_unauthenticated_status_request(self):
        rv = self.flask_app.get("/status")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mock `before_request` callbacks, especially since in this case you're testing that callback.  If your request requires configuration, database data, specific headers, etc., then you set those up when you set up the test app before you create the test client request.

There are of course ways to make this more convenient, but it's the same thing you would do during normal operation.

You've already demonstrated that you know how to set configuration.  `app.config` is available.

Create a test database and set the config to point at it.  Then commit to the database like normal.  Most Flask database extensions require an app context, so push a context first.

```
with app.app_context():
    # commit data
```

The test client's methods [accepts many arguments](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/test/#werkzeug.test.EnvironBuilder) for building a request, including a `headers=` argument.  So make the request with the correct headers.

```
self.flask_app.get('/status', headers={'my_header': 'value'})
```

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't unit test this.  I would functional test it by setting the headers when making the request.  I prefer using [Flask-Webtest](https://flask-webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of the built in test client.

```
from unittest import TestCase
from flask_webtest import TestApp
from main import app, db

class ExampleTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = app
        self.w = TestApp(self.app, db=db, use_session_scopes=True)

    def test(self):
        resp = self.w.get('/status', headers=...)
        assert resp.request.custom_auth_property == 'some value'
```

This code isn't tested but will hopefully put you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I've found I need to liberally use `app.preprocess_request()` to start many of my tests. Also assuming use of pytest + Flask-Webtest, found it useful to use it in my fixture as such:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def testapp(app, db):
    """A flask-webtest TestApp for the functional tests."""
    app.preprocess_request()
    return TestApp(app, db=db)
```